# What is the meaning of the comparator part of the std::priority_queue in C++?

Tags: c++

Priority queue syntax in C++:

```
priority_queue <Type, vector<Type>, ComparisonType > min_heap;
```

If I want to declare a max heap, I use `std::less`, otherwise `std::greater` (min heap). I don't quite get why `std::less` leads to a max heap, and `std::greater` min heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) that explains the concept:

> Compare   -   A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.
>
> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true
>   if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak
>   ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements
>   first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That
>   is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to
>   the weak ordering imposed by Compare.